# "node-gyp build" Fatal error C1083

Tags: node.js, msbuild, node-gyp

I'm trying to run a project on my **windows 10 (x64)** with nodejs.
To run the project, I was given a list of components/packages to install that included Bower, Ruby, Sass, Grunt, MySQL and Redis. Further components included installing node-gyp, node-canvas, Python 2.7 and Microsoft Build Tools 
(Link: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows ).

After installing all the **dependencies**, I keep getting an error message :

> c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\src\binding.cc': No such file or directory [C:\myeffect\build\binding.vcxproj]

I've done everything I could to resolve the error, re-installed everything, added PATH to python on the System Variables, EVERYTHING.

But the error keeps coming. Please someone Help me what to do.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630082/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file

Comment: I am using command prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try it, i solved it.

create C:\myeffect\src\binding.cc。  bingd.cc file is empty file。

Comment: You saved my day. Nobody figure out this issue yet.